# Why is the value of "switch" type parameter passed to a string parameter?

Tags: powershell, parameter-passing

The test code (`test.ps1`):

```
Param(
    [string]$content = $null,
    [switch]$flag = $false
)
Write-Host $content
```

Output:

```
PS C:\Users\powershell> .\test.ps1

PS C:\Users\powershell> .\test.ps1 -flag $true    
True
PS C:\Users\powershell> .\test.ps1 -flag $false
False
PS C:\Users\powershell> .\test.ps1 -flag $true -content "lalala"
lalala
```

No matter I set `$content` to `$null`, or `""`, or without any default value, the output is the same.

So why does `$content` take the value from `$flag`?

Comment: You are not pass any value to `-flag`.

Comment: Switch parameters, in their general usage, are $false if you don't specify them on the command line, and are $true if you do specify them on the command line.  @PetSerAl

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue, what psversion are you using? what os?

Comment: I think the real point of confusion here is that `$true` is interpreted by the parser as a positional argument and implicitly bound to `-Content`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[@PetSerAl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45691877/in-powershell-why-the-value-of-switch-type-parameter-is-passed-to-a-string-pa#comment78341433_45691877) already indicated what your misunderstanding is, but maybe it was a bit too brief, so I'll elaborate a little more.

A `[switch]` parameter doesn't take a value like regular parameters. You normally set it to true or false respectively by providing or omitting the parameter:

```
PS C:\> Get-Content .\test.ps1
Param(
    [string]$Content = $null,
    [switch]$Flag
)
$flag.IsPresent
$Content
PS C:\> .\test.ps1
False

PS C:\> .\test.ps1 -Flag
True
```

Alternatively you can explicitly pass a value by putting a colon between switch parameter and value:

```
PS C:\> .\test.ps1 -Flag:$false
False

PS C:\> .\test.ps1 -Flag:$true
True
```

Whitespace after the colon is allowed, but not before  (`-Flag: $false` passes `$false` as the switch value, `-Flag :$false` doesn't).

If you try to assign the switch value *without* the colon the value is actually passed to the next parameter in line, in your case the `-Content` parameter:

```
PS C:\> .\test.ps1 -Flag $false
True         # value of the parameter $Flag
False        # value of the (positional) parameter $Content
PS C:\> .\test.ps1 -Flag -Content $false
True         # value of the parameter $Flag
False        # value of the (named) parameter $Content
```

If you use `-Flag $true` (without the colon) *and* pass a value to the (named) parameter `-Content` the value `$true` is passed as an unnamed third parameter (accessible via the [automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/about_Automatic_Variables?view=powershell-3.0) `$args`), same as if you put the value at the end of the statement:

```
PS C:\> Get-Content .\test2.ps1
Param(
    [string]$Content = $null,
    [switch]$Flag
)
$flag.IsPresent
$Content
$args[0]
PS C:\> .\test2.ps1 -Flag $false -Content 'something'
True
something
False        # $false passed as unnamed 3rd parameter
PS C:\> .\test2.ps1 -Flag:$false -Content 'something'
False        # $false passed as explicit value of switch parameter $Flag
something
PS C:\> .\test2.ps1 -Flag -Content 'something' $false
True
something
False        # $false passed as unnamed 3rd parameter
```

Comment: Spaces are allowed after colon.

Answer (score 2):

Give this test code a run, calling it as you did in the question. Add this test:

```
C:\Users\powershell> .\test.ps1 -flag
```

Script will illustrate the following points:

- As per 4c74356b41's comment, switches are `$false` unless specified on the command line. So `-flag` sets the `$flag` switch to true; `-flag $true` sets the flag to true *and* passes the argument `$true` to content.
- From this, no need to specify `$flag=$false` in script params
- Added a test so that you can see when `$content` is empty/null as there is also no need for `$content=$null`

---

```
param(
    [string]$content,
    [switch]$flag
)

$test = [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($content)

Write-Output "content: $content"
Write-Output "flag   : $flag"
Write-Output "Is content null: $test"
```

Answer (score 1):

I will add to this that you can assign the value via splatting as well, changing the value via the splat parameter assignment from $true to $false will alter your switch 'detection'. This is useful when you are using another value or property to determine if a switch should be used or not.

```
function FooBar {
    param (
        [switch]
        $Foo
    )
    if ($Foo){
        "Foo"
    }
    else{
        "Bar"
    }
}
$splat = @{
    Foo = $False
}
FooBar @splat
```